# Dynamic array allocation in a for loop throws an error

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-management

I have this for loop:

```
for(int l = 0; l < level_max; ++l) {
    //...
    indexCount[l] = (2*patch_size_level+1) * (patch_size_level - 1);
    GLuint* indices = new GLuint[indexCount[l]];
    //... (for loops in which I fill indices)
    delete[] indices;
}
```

(full code snippet can be found here: https://gist.github.com/1915777)

For some reason this throws the following memory exception at `GLuint* indices = new GLuint[indexCount[l]];`

> Demo(12783,0x7fff7367e960) malloc: *** error for object 0x1028cd408:
>   incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified
>   after being freed.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not assigning more than `indexCount[l]` values to my indices array. (I've checked this). How do you properly delete a dynamic array in a loop like this.

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `(2*patch_size_level+1) * (patch_size_level - 1)`?

Comment: Look for index out of bounds, it might result in some strange errors from time to time.

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector<GLuint>`?

Comment: Adding the line `std::cout << current_index << " " << (2*patch_size_level+1) * (patch_size_level - 1) << std::endl;` results in the following output: 
> 2144 2144
> 560 560
> 152 152
> 44 44
> 14 14

Comment: @KennyTM no particular reason other than that I'm fairly unfamiliar with even the most basic features of the std library.

Comment: @Jan Fix that. It’s a serious shortcoming when programming C++. That said, this problem sounds more complex and unrelated to that. +1 for well-asked question.

Comment: Memory allocation/deallocation within a inner loop is a performance killer **and** it will fragment your address space. This is a big fat no-go. If it were in some project I participated, it wouldn't get through a code review I did. I recommend using a std::vector instead and only increase its reserved capacity, never decreasing it.

Comment: I need to feed raw data to OpenGL when binding the buffer though, I'm not even sure if that possible while using a std::vector without making a function which converts the vector into a proper array, wouldnt that be even slower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues has been resolved.. It was a prior `new[]` call (in another method) which didnt have the proper size, which caused the problem here. Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: PS: For those interested, this method is part of an open-source game engine which can be found here https://github.com/jwbuurlage/Motor and is updated regularly. Input is more than welcome.

Comment: Note: This is exactly why most C++ users suggest using `std::vector` instead of direct `new[]` calls. You *can't* get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe unrelated, but there is a possible read buffer overflow on this line :

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GL_UNSIGNED_INT) * indexCount[l], indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I don't know how `sizeof(GL_UNSIGNED_INT)` compares to `sizeof(GLuint)` on your system, but check out your code for this kind of errors.

Comment: Fixed but was unfortunatly not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's throwing a memory exception on the following line:

```
GLuint* indices = new GLuint[indexCount[l]];
```

there are two (memory-related) things that I see that could go wrong:

1. An out of bounds access in indexCount. Are you sure you have allocated space for indexCount? Are you sure it is of size greater than l when this exception throws? Try debugging and checking to make sure indexCount isn't null and that l isn't greater than the size of indexCount right before the exception throws. See if it throws in the first iteration of your for loop or in a middle iteration.
2. C++'s `new` not being able to allocate enough memory. This is the only other memory related error I can see from this line of code. However, I don't see any way that error message could be related to not having enough memory to allocate, so I'm doubtful that it's this one.

You really need to debug to get more information.

- Is indexCount null when it's being accessed (when the exception throws)
- Does the exception throw on the first value or an intermediary value of the for loop
- Does the exception actually throw on that specific line?
- Check the size of indexCount and where you allocate it and make sure l isn't greater than this size.

Comment: It throws the exception at `l = 0`, and I do allocate memory for indexCount (see the gist). As an answer to your other remarks: 1) indexCount is not null when its being accessed. 2) No, at `l=0`. 3) It's pretty random, but it gives a SIGABRT either at that line, or the `delete[] indices` line. Sometimes it does work, it seems random. 4) see 2). I really dont see what else could be it though..

Answer (score 0):

> Adding the line `std::cout << current_index << " " <<
>   (2*patch_size_level+1) * (patch_size_level - 1) << std::endl;` results
>   in the following output:

Where did you add this line? IME `current_index` reaches 8126 before the crash, `indexCount[l]` being, as in your case, 2144. Here's what we have:

```
patch_size=64
level_max=5
patch_size_level=33
indexCount[0]=2144
```

but you execute the inner loop `(patch_size * (patch_size-1))` times, which is 4032, and you two increments of `current_index` per inner loop, which gives us over 8000.

You might have mixed up  patch_size and patch_size_level at some point, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I added this at the bottom of the outermost loop. (just above delete indices[]). For higher levels I increment the counters with a power of two, so I do not execute the loops  `(patch_size * (patch_size-1))` times for those. For the lowest possible level we have `(patch_size_level - 1) * (patch_size_level*2 + 1)) increments` and since `patch_size_level` for `l = 0` is simply `patch_size` we have `(patch_size - 1) * (2*patch_size + 1)`.

Comment: Furthermore, patch_size should be of the form $2^n + 1$. I'm currently testing with 65.